# Split a string in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I have a function that accepts a message in String form. The message looks like this : "HTTP/1.1 GET /1/ \n"

I have been using the java.String.split method to break down the string into three smaller substrings, version, command, and number. Then I reconstruct the oringal string from the substrings and output it.

However, when I run teh function the program results in ArrayIndex out of bounds : 1, but still functions properly. But when I run the program step by step in the debugger (netbeans) the program does not result in the ArrayIndex out of bounds nonesense and functions as normal

Any suggestions?

Sam

```
String output = "";

        String[] tokens = clientMessage.split(" ");
        String version = tokens[0];
        String command = tokens[1];
        String potNum = tokens[2];
        output = version + " " + command + " " + potNum;
```

EDIT yes, the program is multithreaded, the clientMsessage string contains "HTTP/1.1 GET /1/ \n" all the time, the value fo clientMessage never changes. The clientMessage is a string sent from a client program and then processed on the server and the output is snet back tot eh client but I keep getting the array errors

Comment: what is `clientMessage`? Often, if you see difference between behavior during debug with tracing and during normal run, it is an indication of a data-race, **is your program multithreaded?** and specifically, does it generate `clientMessage` asynchroniously?

Comment: My guess is that your clientMessage value is different between runs.  Verify that clientMessage is the same by printing the value out in both runs.

Comment: How long is the clientMessage? If there are not enough tokens in the client message, then you will get ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception when you do command = tokens[1]

Comment: What line exactly throws OOB Exception?

Comment: Try printing to the standard output the length of tokens. The code fragment you provide seems to be correct so even if there is some error I don't think it is in it.

Comment: It's redundant to assign `""` to `output` since you're overwriting it a moment later.

Comment: Yes the program is Multithreaded, clientMessage is sjut a string that is send to the server from the client program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArrayIndexOutOfBounds arises when you are accessing index of an array which does not have any values means in your case tokens[1] does not exists. When debugging are you using same string as input??

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you print out/log your inputs.  I suspect you are doing something differently when you debug your program.  Its possible this works the first time you call it but when its called again, it fails.

Add before the split.

```
System.out.println("clientMessage >" + clientMessage +"<");
```

---

If your output looks like

```
clientMessage >HTCPCP/1.0 PROPFIND /1/< 
clientMessage >HTCPCP/1.0 PROPFIND /1/< 
clientMessage ><
```

It appears you have an empty request message. I imagine this means the client will not be sending more requests and you have to handle this differently.

Comment: Output  :                                                 clientMessage >HTCPCP/1.0 PROPFIND /1/<
ouput >HTCPCP/1.0 PROPFIND /1/<
clientMessage ><

Comment: So you have an empty client message. Your request appears to be very different to your template.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry  this is not an answer but just an additional question to find what is actually wrong and comments are too small to put that much code. The following works for me, so one of your asumptions is wrong:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String clientMessage = "HTTP/1.1 GET /1/ \n";
        String[] tokens = clientMessage.split(" ");
        String version = tokens[0];
        String command = tokens[1];
        String potNum = tokens[2];
        System.err.println(version + " " + command + " " + potNum);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It runs OK on my side. I would have to guess that sometimes clientMessage is a value that does not contain enough spaces to be seperated in 3 parts.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is more to the code than you are including here. I put your code in a class as follows and it compiles and runs without error. Is there something missing?

```
public class Andrew {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    String output = "";
    String clientMessage = "HTTP/1.1 GET /1/ \n";

        String[] tokens = clientMessage.split(" ");
        String version = tokens[0];
        String command = tokens[1];
        String potNum = tokens[2];
        output = version + " " + command + " " + potNum;

    System.out.println(output);

    }
```

}